# Are there any Javascript or PHP libraries or packages to help AWS cron expressions?

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-cloudwatch

When you create EventBridge or CloudWatch rules in AWS, you use [Schedule Expressions.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) There are two types:

- Cron Expressions
- Rate Expressions

When creating cron expressions (below figure is on CloudWatch service), you can see the next 10 Trigger Dates on the console. Is there a library or code snippet provided by AWS that allows you to parse the cron expression and display the trigger dates (past and future)?

[image: AWS Cron Expression]

Comment: There are cron expression parsers, e.g. [cron-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron-parser). Not exactly sure what do you aim to achieve?

Comment: It's in my question, "parse the cron expression and display the trigger dates (past and future)?" like shown in the diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [cron-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron-parser) as suggested by Marcin. Worked out pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

I think this npm package may work for you : https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-cron-parser. To display the next 10 dates, you can use a loop. To display in GMT, you can use Date.toUTCString(). Hope this helps.

Comment: Hye Vin, Thanks. I see that you created the package. I ended up using cron-parser for my project but I will check it out. I also wanted past dates when it was last run. Do you think you can add that functionality in?

Comment: Also tried the example code but doesn't seem to work https://runkit.com/embed/bjmltgd2e8x3

Comment: Hi @dnafication, I chose a bad example :) because that cron expression is only for May 2020 so it's returning null because there is no future occurrences. I'll put up a better example. Btw, I wrote this package for my work at my company, Beem, so the credit goes to them :) Although we don't have a need for seeing past occurrences, I may be able to take a look this weekend and implement that if it's not too much work.

Comment: Feel free to request the enhancement on our GitHub repo https://github.com/beemhq/aws-cron-parser Thanks!

Comment: Hi @dnafication I added "prev" feature. If you have chance, let me know what you think. Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know of any python libraries for parsing and converting AWS cron strings to a list of calendar dates?